# Show/Hide sticky icons on "Click", WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hide

https://jsfiddle.net/x5ue890v/1/

I have some sticky icons on my Wordpress site but how do I hide them based on "click" on the screen. Above link show you what I want to achieve.

I add:

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;   
}
```

to my theme CSS and:

```
function social_effect() { ?>
<script>
  $('body').click(function() {
  $('.ct-socials').toggle();});
</script>

<?php }

add_action('wp_head','social_effect');
```

to my theme "function.php" but doesn't work... Any solution?

---

- Update

  I want to hide:

`<div class="ct-socials std-tab-slide">My Social Icon</div>`

Comment: you need to add your css on your question so we can identify what ID are you using or class are you using for the social media section you want to hide.

Comment: Ok.. did you add the library on your html or on top of you script when you run it? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>. I can recreate this for you let me know.

Comment: I made a sample for you so you can see how it should be done look below code and try to put it on your code.

Comment: @Crystal Indeed this was the answer for my clue, thank you for all of your responds!
I just found out that loading the .js is breaking my theme nav. How could I prevent this for happening?

Comment: I would suggest you create a new ID or class and put it inside  <div class="ct-socials std-tab-slide my-social"> like my-social then thats the one you will use to toggle it. Let me know if that will works for you.

Comment: @Crystal Sorry not working either... :/

Comment: you are prob bumpin into some other command or code. Lets continue in chatbox so we dont flood your post.

Comment: I only have 1 reputation at the moment, not yet enough to chat so please feel free to contact me on [WhatsApp](https://www.pontuseriksson.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/IMG_8850.jpg)

Comment: Alright. Ill try to reach out when I got a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. I dont't have all your code but this should work. Add all your script library inside the head or on top of your functions. Let me know

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click(function() {
  $('.ct-socials').toggle(); 
  });
  
});
```

```css
.ct-socials {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button>Click ME </button>
<div class="ct-socials std-tab-slide">
  <div>My Social Icon</div>
  <div>My Social Icon</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

Just add this JavaScript line before the function

Comment: I already mentioned this to him on the comment.

Comment: @SuryaBasak this was the solution for my situation! Thank you so much!

Comment: @PontusEriksson I mentioned this on my comment above. This is what I said "Ok.. did you add the library on your html or on top of you script when you run it? <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/…>. I can recreate this for you let me know."

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.